# How to check whether one child exists in XML

Tags: xslt, tei

I have an xslt-script that transforms a tei:bibl Element to HTML

```
<xsl:template match="tei:bibl//tei:author">
    <span class="smallcaps">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:surname"/>
    </span>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:forename"/>
    <xsl:if test="tei:nameLink">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:nameLink"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test=".[following-sibling::tei:author]">
    <xsl:text> / </xsl:text> 
        <span class="smallcaps">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:surname"/>
        </span>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:forename"/>
        <xsl:if test="tei:nameLink">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:nameLink"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text> , </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The XML looks like this:

```
        <bibl xml:id="capitani_ua_bannerherr">
            <abbr>
                <surname type="author">Capitani</surname> u.a., Bannerherr</abbr>
            <author>
                <forename>François</forename>
                <nameLink>de</nameLink>
                <surname>Capitani</surname>
            </author>
            <author>
                <surname>Weck</surname>
                <forename>Hervé</forename>
                <nameLink>de</nameLink>
            </author>
            <title>Bannerherr [Venner]</title>
            <bibl>
                <title>Historisches Lexikon der Schweiz (HLS)</title>
                <date>Version vom 07.05.2009</date>
            </bibl>
            <ref target="http://www.hls-dhs-dss.ch/textes/d/D8612.php" type="ex">[Online]</ref>
        </bibl>
```

My HTML is like this:

```
<span id="capitani_ua_bannerherr" class="rs-ref">
    <span class="smallcaps">Capitani</span>, François de,  / 
    <span class="smallcaps"> Capitani</span>, François de , 
    <span class="smallcaps">Weck</span>, Hervé de, Bannerherr [Venner], in: Historisches Lexikon der Schweiz (HLS), Version vom 07.05.2009<a href="http://www.hls-dhs-dss.ch/textes/d/D8612.php"> [Online]
</a>.
</span>
```

The template does as it is supposed to. However, It doubles the first entry (here `<span class="smallcaps"> Vapitani </span>, Francois de,` )

I have tried adding an `<xsl:choose>` that looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:bibl//tei:author">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="[count(tei:bibl//tei:author)=1]">
                <span class="smallcaps">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:surname"/>
                </span>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:forename"/>
                    <xsl:if test="tei:nameLink">
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:nameLink"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=".[following-sibling::tei:author]">
        <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
            <span class="smallcaps">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:surname"/>
            </span>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:forename"/>
            <xsl:if test="tei:nameLink">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:nameLink"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text> , </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

This should produce output like this:

```
<span id="capitani_ua_bannerherr" class="rs-ref">
        <span class="smallcaps">Capitani</span>, François de,  / 
        <span class="smallcaps">Weck</span>, Hervé de, Bannerherr [Venner], in: Historisches Lexikon der Schweiz (HLS), Version vom 07.05.2009<a href="http://www.hls-dhs-dss.ch/textes/d/D8612.php"> [Online]
    </a>.
</span>
```

What am I doing wrong?
I am not looking for any specific version of XSLT, we can use XSLT 1 -3.

all the best,
K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current template says *"if there is a following author, output the surname and forename"*. It does *not* say "output the surname and forename of the following author".

I'm not 100% sure, but you seem to want the following:

- a list of authors per `<tei:bib>`
- 2nd author separated from the first with `/`
- any further author separated with `,`

Let's write that down exactly like that:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:bibl//tei:author">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 2"> / </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 2"> , </xsl:if>
    <span class="smallcaps">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:surname" />
    </span>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:forename" />
    <xsl:if test="tei:nameLink">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:nameLink" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Now you can invoke that in a straight-forward manner

```
<xsl:template match="tei:bibl">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:author" />
    <!-- ...output the title etc here --->
</xsl:template>
```

and get (formatted for readability):

```
<span xmlns:tei="tei" class="smallcaps">Capitani</span>, François de
/ <span xmlns:tei="tei" class="smallcaps">Weck</span>, Hervé de
```

Comment: Seems I was unclear, despite trying to very clear :-D 
if there is more than one author I want each author separated by a slash. 
seems like <xsl:if test="position() %gt; 1" > could do the trick ? 
I came up with a working solution, I think (very verbose), thus a pastebin: 
https://pastebin.com/kF3bSyXz

Comment: @kev Yes, if you don't need that distinction between 2nd and following, remove it. :) My main point is that the XSLT processor applies the template for you (multiple times if need be) and that you can use `position()` for this. You don't need to repeat yourself in an `<xsl:if>`.

Comment: Just for clarification: `position()` does not refer to the position of the node in the XML tree here. It refers to the position of the node in the "processing queue": `<xsl:apply-templates select="tei:author" />` selects all `<tei:author>` nodes and finds templates for them. `position() = 2` would be true for the second selected node, `position() > 1` would be true for all but the first, etc.

Comment: Thanks :-) this saved quite some code :-D I need to work on my XSLT ...